# SSL error while connecting to Openfire from java-smack client

Tags: java, ssl, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am recently working on Openfire client. I've got this strange issue that I couldn't figure out so far (i've got some clues, but still no solid solution).
We've got 2 openfire servers:

- first that we were using for testing it was hosted on normal pc conected to the internet through adsl, server was behind NAT, everything configured smoothly, working perfect. Our client was connecting without any issues.
- second (let's call it production) professional dedicated server located somewhere in germany with OF instaled, same OS as on the testing one, OF set up in exactly the same way

Now when connecting to production from our client we experianced following issue when trying to authenticate:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
>       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:806)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:267)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.sendPacket(XMPPConnection.java:445)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.NonSASLAuthentication.authenticate(NonSASLAuthentication.java:69)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:352)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:203)
>       at Main.connectToJabber(Main.java:31)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:16)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.sendPacket(XMPPConnection.java:445)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.NonSASLAuthentication.authenticate(NonSASLAuthentication.java:69)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:362)
>       at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:203)
>       at Main.connectToJabber(Main.java:31)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:16)

Now the funniest part: when I connect to the production server using our client from my flat i don't see that error, when we are connecting to the production from other developer flat we've got this error, we've got different internet providers (i don't know if that may have something to do with that).
We've spent all night looking at it and so far no clue.
We wrote basic code just to check the connection:

```
public static void connect() {
    ConnectionConfiguration cc = new ConnectionConfiguration("prod ip",
            5222);
    cc.setCompressionEnabled(true);
    cc.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    Connection connection = new XMPPConnection(cc);
    try {
        connection.connect();
        connection.login(login, pass, "resource");
        System.out.println(connection.isSecureConnection() +  " " + connection.isUsingCompression());

    } catch (XMPPException e1) {
        e1.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Some observations:

- When line connection.login(...) commented, there is no error, so whatever is causing the error is there
- When connecting the testing server System.out... writes true false,
- When connecting the production server System.out... writes false false
- Tried with all combinations of: cc.setCompressionEnabled() cc.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(); (true, true, false true, true false, false false)
- despite the error, user is logged in
  To sum up:

Connection with testing environment works always, with production: from my location - no problem, other location - mentioned error, 
we use SMACK API 3.2.1

One of the ideas was that it has to do something with the certificates.

Any hints or ideas highly appriciated

Comment: Check this: http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/42807

Comment: I did already, this question is not answered as you can see (or not)

Comment: No idea what you mean by 'or not', but did you try to 'sleep' between `connect` and `login`? It may be a workaround or just a prove that you have the same issue!

Comment: Hmmm, apparently it works, in our case 2000ms is enough, sorry for me previous post, we spent 12h with that without success, I've been looking at that thread for like 10 times, i guess that "not answerd" made me think that its not helpfull, anyways, now im wondering why when we tried to connect to the testing server everything was just fine

Comment: Hm, maybe it's about network latency? I'd just look into the smack code (connect method)...

Comment: I guess it might have to do something with latency, I don't have time to look at it now, but we'll have to investigate that later on, so ill share the results. Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a `sleep(x)` between the `connect()` and the `login()` call could fix this. A few seconds for the `sleep()` should be enough.
<sup>[Source](http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/42807)</sup>

Comment: yes, that's the solution, however x varies and it has to be checked per case

Answer (score 2):

Bad bad solution! because u don't know connection speed and also u stop your app from continuing to login if connection established at early moments.
A solution that I can offer for now is to `addConnectionListener` and call `login()` in 'reconnectionSuccessful()' function, and I hope this function will call for the first time not just after connection dropped  and connected again! if not, It shows the bad architecture of smack library.

Answer (score 0):

I also use a sleep after connect() also... it's not ideal sure, but it's a reliable workaround.